# Laravel/Eloquent relationship issue

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a model called "Users", with the following information:

```
id
name
status_id
```

I have a model called "Status", with the following information:

```
id
description
```

When performing a raw query, one would naturally join the two tables on `users.status_id = status.id` however I would like to use Laravel's Eloquent ORM to grab a user's status text.

eg. `User::find(1)->status()->description`

There are many different functions provided, such as `has_one`, `has_many`, and `belongs_to`, but none of these work.  Does anyone have any ideas on how I can do something like this?

Comment: *"none of these work"* is not an acceptable problem description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found an answer.  I can do the above by running a Fluent query instead of using a native relationship:

```
 public function status() {

    return Status::where('id', '=', $this->status_id)->first();
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

The way you have your database setup, you would add a has one user method to the Status model.

In your STATUS model:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->has_one('User');
}
```

This would let you query by status but not by user. To implement the functionality you want, ie `User::find(1)->status()->description` you would need to have your database look like this

```
Users

    id
    name

Status

    id
    description
    user_id
```

Now you would implement the following in your user model

```
public function status()
{
    return $this->has_one('Status');
}
```

allowing you to use:

```
User::find(1)->status()->description;
```

This would allow you a one to one relationship between Users and Status. To implement a one to many relationship, i.e one user has many status' (probably not the best example) you can use the same database set up as above but instead in the user model you would have your `user()` function return:

```
$this->has_many('Status');
```

Comment: Thanks - upvote for an in-depth answer.  Unfortunately changing the database structure around like you suggest is not normal form for my purposes.  It turns out the answer I was looking for wasn't really in line with the question I asked and I've found an answer I listed below.

Comment: No worries Darren, I just wrote out how Laravel expects your database to look like for the relationships to work. :)